# Chart.js is not rendered until zoom in in angular 8

Tags: angular, chart.js, primeng

i have an angular 8 application, and i'm using primeng-lts 8.2.5 components, i'm trying to use chart.js version 2.9.3 in my application, but the pie chart doesn't show up until i zoom in, also the labels.

in my pie chart i'm displaying counts by status, as in the code below, i'm loading `status[]` from an http call, then for each `status`, i'm calling an http method that return the counts :

**HTML :**

```
<p-chart type="pie" [data]="numberByStatus" >
</p-chart>
```

**TS :**

```
  numberByStatus : any;
  labelsByStatus: String[] = [];
  countsByStatus: number[] = [];


this.service.getStatus()
  .subscribe((res: status[]) => {


    res.forEach(element => {         
    this.service.getCountByStatus(element.id)
        .subscribe((count: number) => {
          this.countsByStatus.push(count);
          this.labelsByStatus.push(element.designation)
        }, (err) => {
          alert('Faild to load counts');
        });
    });


  }, (err) => {
    alert('Faild to load data');
  });


this.numberByStatus = {
  labels: this.labelsByStatus,
  datasets: [
    {
      data: this.countsByStatus,
      backgroundColor: [
        "#FF6384",
        "#36A2EB",
        "#FFCE56"
      ],
      hoverBackgroundColor: [
        "#FF6384",
        "#36A2EB",
        "#FFCE56"
      ]
    }]
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look the problem is that your `numberByStatus` object reference doesn't change when you are trying to push the items into `labelsByStatus` or `countsByStatus` arrays

try like this.

**at first import all of these items for both solutions

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs/internal/observable/forkJoin';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

and

```js
numberByStatus : any;
labelsByStatus: String[] = [];
countsByStatus: number[] = [];


this.service.getStatus()
  .subscribe((res: status[]) => {

    const requestsList = [];   // define the request list property and store all of the requests here
    res.forEach(element => {  
    // push the request into the array
    requestsList.push(
       this.service.getCountByStatus(element.id).pipe(
          map(count => {   
              // push the count into countsByStatus
              this.countsByStatus.push(count);
              // push the element.designation into labelsByStatus
              this.labelsByStatus.push(element.designation);
              // return the count and the corresponding element
              // I think this can be helpfull. if you will need to know the count for the each element
              return { element: element, count: count }
          }))
       );

    });  
       // send all of the requests
       forkJoin(requestsList).subscribe(
             (response: {element: status, count: number}[]) => {
               // and now this line will work only once
                this.numberByStatus = { ...this.numberByStatus };
             },
             (err) => {
                alert('Faild to load data');
             }
        );

  }, (err) => {
    alert('Faild to load data');
  });

 this.numberByStatus = {
    labels: this.labelsByStatus,
    datasets: [
       {
           data: this.countsByStatus,
           backgroundColor: [
              "#FF6384",
              "#36A2EB",
              "#FFCE56"
           ],
           hoverBackgroundColor: [
              "#FF6384",
              "#36A2EB",
              "#FFCE56"
           ]
       }
    ]

 };
```

or

```js
numberByStatus : any;
labelsByStatus: String[] = [];
countsByStatus: number[] = [];


this.service.getStatus()
  .subscribe((res: status[]) => {

    const requestsList = [];   // define the request list property and store all of the requests here
    res.forEach(element => {  
    // push the request into the array
    requestsList.push(
       this.service.getCountByStatus(element.id).pipe(
          map(count => {   
               // push the count into countsByStatus
              this.countsByStatus.push(count);
              // push the element.designation into labelsByStatus
              this.labelsByStatus.push(element.designation);
              // return the count and the corresponding element
              // I think this can be helpfull. if you will need to know the count for the each element
              return { element: element, count: count }
          }))
       );
    });  
    
       forkJoin(requestsList).subscribe(
             (response: {element: status, count: number}[]) => {
              // and now this line will work only once
               this.numberByStatus = {
                   labels: this.labelsByStatus,
                   datasets: [
                      {
                         data: this.countsByStatus,
                         backgroundColor: [
                             "#FF6384",
                             "#36A2EB",
                             "#FFCE56"
                         ],
                         hoverBackgroundColor: [
                             "#FF6384",
                             "#36A2EB",
                             "#FFCE56"
                         ]
                     }
                 ]

             };
    
             },
             (err) => {
                alert('Faild to load data');
             }
          );

  }, (err) => {
    alert('Faild to load data');
  });
```

Comment: that was exactly the problem, i tried the second proposition and worked, thank you.

Comment: @BillyDEKAR also you can use formJoin to do the all requests at once, to improve the performance, How I could see you are sending the request on each iteration and the change detection will work on every ` this.numberByStatus = something`

Comment: @BillyDEKAR I have updated the answer. Please can you check one more time

Comment: what is the point of returning { element: element, count: count }, if it is never used in the forkJoin?

Comment: @BillyDEKAR if you will need it in the future you don't need to do any changes. just for that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the asynchronous nature of Angular. The chart is created before its `labels` and the `data` have been defined inside `this.numberByStatus`.

There are basically two solutions to solve this issue.

1. Make sure the chart is created only once `this.numberByStatus` is fully furnished.
2. Update the chart programmatically after `this.numberByStatus` is completely defined.

Without seeing more of your code, its hard to provide the best solution however. I also don't know primeng-lts.

- You could try to only conditionally include the chart in your HTML template using [`*ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf). It should evaluate to `true` only once `this.numberByStatus` is ready to be used (solution 1).
- In case you can obtain a reference to the `chart` object, invoke its `update()` method after you redefined `this.numberByStatus` (solution 2).